# Button to dynamically choose email template based on user's language

Tags: email, send-email

I have created two email template on two different language now i need a button to send the email template to user based on the account/user's language preference. only 2 type language is there dutch and french.
Like if user language is french and he click on the send email button email with french translated template will go to the user and if user language is dutch then email template with dutch language will be send.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating 2 templates, create one template using Custom Labels and then translate using the Translation Workbench.

Then the system will automatically pick the user's language when sending the email.

You can find how to create Custom Labels in the Setup Menu, under "Create".